# Present UINavigationViewController with UIViewController pushed (only showing one animation)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an **UINavigationViewController** which has a **UITableViewController** as is root view. When the user selects a cell a **UIViewController** is pushed in.

My Main **UIViewController** has a button that presents the **UINavigationViewController** modally, but I also have another button that i want to use to go directly into a pushed **UIViewController** of the **UINavigationViewController**.

By using the following code, both animations are shown, the **UINavigationViewController** happens first, and when completed the **UIViewController** takes place.

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];
UINavigationController *navController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"SettingsNavigationController"];

UIViewController *viewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"MyInfoViewController"];


[self presentViewController:navController
                   animated:YES
                 completion:^
{
    [navController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}];
```

This looks nice, but what i want is to show the pushed **UIViewController** with just 1 animation (or even without animation) as if my main view was presenting it, but keeping the functionality that the when the user presses back on this **UIViewController** it goes back to the **UINavigationViewController**.

If I set both "animated" to NO, the **UIViewController** shows pretty quick but a glance of the **UINavigationViewController** can still be seen.

A possible solution that occurs to me would be to take a "snapshot" of the main view and pass it to the **UINavigationViewController** to use it to hide its contents while the wanted **UIViewController** appears.

Note: It should work for iOS 7 and 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push the view controller without animation **before** presenting the navigation controller.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];
UINavigationController *navController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"SettingsNavigationController"];

UIViewController *viewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"MyInfoViewController"];

[navController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];

[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```